# trying to install MPLABX on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS - installer can't find libstdc++

Tags: apt, gcc

I'm trying to install MPLABX on my 64-bit linux box. The installer says I'm missing these files:

```
libstdc++.so
libexpat.so
libX11.so
libXest.so
```

So I have already run:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

I try to run:

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6

# and it says:
libstdc++6 is already the newest version
```

I read somewhere to try to run apt-file:

```
sudo apt-file find libstdc++.so.6
```

and I get the following output:

```
libstdc++6: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
libstdc++6: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
libstdc++6: /usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.py
libstdc++6-4.4-dbg: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/debug/libstdc++.so.6
libstdc++6-4.4-dbg: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/debug/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
libstdc++6-4.6-dbg: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/debug/libstdc++.so.6
libstdc++6-4.6-dbg: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/debug/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
libstdc++6-4.7-dbg: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/debug/libstdc++.so.6
libstdc++6-4.7-dbg: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/debug/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
libstdc++6-4.7-dbg-armel-cross: /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/debug/libstdc++.so.6
libstdc++6-4.7-dbg-armel-cross: /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/debug/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
libstdc++6-4.7-dbg-armel-cross: /usr/lib/debug/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
libstdc++6-4.7-dbg-armel-cross: /usr/lib/debug/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.17-gdb.py
libstdc++6-4.7-dbg-armhf-cross: /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/debug/libstdc++.so.6
libstdc++6-4.7-dbg-armhf-cross: /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/debug/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
libstdc++6-4.8-dbg: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
libstdc++6-4.8-dbg: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.py
libstdc++6-4.8-dbg: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/debug/libstdc++.so.6
libstdc++6-4.8-dbg: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/debug/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
libstdc++6-4.8-dbg: /usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/debug/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.py
libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-arm64-cross: /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/debug/libstdc++.so.6
libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-arm64-cross: /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/debug/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-arm64-cross: /usr/lib/debug/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-arm64-cross: /usr/lib/debug/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.py
libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-arm64-cross: /usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/debug/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.py
libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-armhf-cross: /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/debug/libstdc++.so.6
libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-armhf-cross: /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/debug/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-armhf-cross: /usr/lib/debug/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-armhf-cross: /usr/lib/debug/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.py
libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-armhf-cross: /usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/debug/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.py
libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-powerpc-cross: /usr/lib/debug/usr/powerpc-linux-gnu/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-powerpc-cross: /usr/lib/debug/usr/powerpc-linux-gnu/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.py
libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-powerpc-cross: /usr/powerpc-linux-gnu/lib/debug/libstdc++.so.6
libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-powerpc-cross: /usr/powerpc-linux-gnu/lib/debug/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-powerpc-cross: /usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/powerpc-linux-gnu/lib/debug/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.py
libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-ppc64el-cross: /usr/lib/debug/usr/powerpc64le-linux-gnu/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-ppc64el-cross: /usr/lib/debug/usr/powerpc64le-linux-gnu/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.py
libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-ppc64el-cross: /usr/powerpc64le-linux-gnu/lib/debug/libstdc++.so.6
libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-ppc64el-cross: /usr/powerpc64le-linux-gnu/lib/debug/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
libstdc++6-4.8-dbg-ppc64el-cross: /usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/powerpc64le-linux-gnu/lib/debug/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.py
libstdc++6-arm64-cross: /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/libstdc++.so.6
libstdc++6-arm64-cross: /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
libstdc++6-arm64-cross: /usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.py
libstdc++6-armel-cross: /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/libstdc++.so.6
libstdc++6-armel-cross: /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
libstdc++6-armhf-cross: /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libstdc++.so.6
libstdc++6-armhf-cross: /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
libstdc++6-armhf-cross: /usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.py
libstdc++6-powerpc-cross: /usr/powerpc-linux-gnu/lib/libstdc++.so.6
libstdc++6-powerpc-cross: /usr/powerpc-linux-gnu/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
libstdc++6-powerpc-cross: /usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/powerpc-linux-gnu/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.py
libstdc++6-ppc64el-cross: /usr/powerpc64le-linux-gnu/lib/libstdc++.so.6
libstdc++6-ppc64el-cross: /usr/powerpc64le-linux-gnu/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
libstdc++6-ppc64el-cross: /usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/powerpc64le-linux-gnu/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.19-gdb.py
```

(among others which I've left out)

so I went to `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu` and did a:

```
find . -name "libstdc++*"
```

and got the following:

```
./4.8/libstdc++.so

./4.8/libstdc++.a
```

In the 4th line of the output it says `"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/debug..."`
and I don't have a debug directory at that location.

Any ideas?

Comment: I did a:  "sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6" and it seemed to fix the problem, now the installer can't find: libexpat.so, libX11.so and libXext.so

Comment: I'm showing a link in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.0

Comment: sudo apt-get install libx11-6:i386 solved the problem of finding libX11.so

Comment: sudo apt-get install libexpat-dev:i386 solved the problem of finding libexpat.so

Comment: If you solved the problem, please add that as answer and accept it :)

Comment: and sudo apt-get install libXext-dev:i386 seemed to solve finding libXest.so

Answer (score 1):

I installed (using sudo apt-get install)

libx11-6:i386

libexpat-dev:i386

libXest-dev:i386

lib32stdc++6

and it installs fine now.

Comment: For ubuntu 18.04 replace libXest-dev:i386 with libxext-dev:i386 (note - lowercase x) and lib32stdc++6 with libstdc++6:i386